# Is hamburger a compound word?

Tags: compounds

My ego is on the line here.

My husband is insisting hamburger is a compound word because ham+burger.

I say it's not because it's hamburg+er.

Google keeps saying he's right, but really, what does google know?

Comment: It appears that the German name comes from [*Hammaburg*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=hammaburg+etymology). which is a compound: *castle* in the *meadow* or *bay*. But not *burger* in the *bun* :)

Comment: I don't think so, see here: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=hamburger)

Comment: @BillJ At that link there is no other hint as to origin of the "ham" in *Hamburg beef* or *hamburger sandwich*

Comment: @DjinTonic It's indecisive.

Comment: When I was young(er) "hamburger" was the word; "burger" came into use later, presumably as an abbreviation. (Presumably the shorter form did not get to Australia for some time.) "Burgher" is different, only cannibals would eat them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is easily answered by looking in the Online Etymological Dictionary.

Comment: Voting to reopen since this is an excellent example of [rebracketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing)--in fact, it's the example Wikipedia uses to explain that phenomenon.

Comment: 'Google keeps saying he's right, but really, what does google know?' needs deleting; I'll edit it out myself if not removed. Any references involved should be quoted and attributed. One can even access OED (with restrictions) via Google, and other quality dictionaries are freely available..

Answer (score 3):

The sandwich "hamburger" is named after the town where it was invented, "Hamburg, New York", which is in turn named after Hamburg, Germany.

No, "hamburger" is not a combination of "ham" and "burger".  It goes the opposite way... "hamburger" came first, then (later) "burger" was a shortened form of it.

---

DjinTonic commented:
It appears that the German name comes from *Hammaburg*. which **is** a compound: castle in the meadow or bay.

Comment: Could you provide some evidence that hamburgers are named after Hamburg, New York? [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hamburger#:~:text=hamburger%20(n.),as%20a%20variety%20of%20hen.) doesn't think so,  There is a German ground meat dish known as a "Hamburger". It doesn't bear that much resemblance to an American hamburger, but I suspect that this is where the name comes from.

Comment: 'Evidence suggests that either the United States or Germany (the city of Hamburg) was the first country where two slices of bread and a ground beef patty were combined into a "hamburger sandwich" and sold.' ["History of the hamburger"--Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_hamburger)

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent example of **rebracketing**--so excellent, in fact, that it's [the example Wikipedia uses:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing)

> **Rebracketing** (also known as **resegmentation** or **metanalysis**) is a process in historical linguistics where a word originally derived from one set of morphemes is broken down or bracketed into a different set. For example, hamburger, originally from *Hamburg+er*, has been rebracketed into *ham+burger*, and *burger* was later reused as a productive morpheme in coinages such as *cheeseburger.*

In short: historically, the word was divided into *Hamburg+er,* but it has since been widely reanalyzed as *ham+burger,* given the shortened form *burger,* which has enabled the production of new terms like *cheeseburger.*

Comment: Rebracketing has been covered before, but not a bad example. But dictionary research would have answered the given question.